# how to show persian or arabic numbers in Magento?

Tags: php, ce-1.8.1.0, javascript, css, html

how to convert English numbers to persian/arabic numbers in Magento? (in all frontend)

i got this but i don't know how to use it or where to copy it.

```
function fanum($englishnumbers)
{
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’0′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’1′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’2′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’3′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’4′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’5′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’6′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’7′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’8′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);
$englishnumbers = str_replace(’9′ , ‘PN’ , $englishnumbers);

return $englishnumbers;
}
```

> "PN" will replaced by "persian or arabic numbers"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution would be to use Javascript.
Since prices are wrapped in a `span` tag with some class/id. You can read those values and convert it to arabic number using window load event.

For english to arabic number conversion You can use some jQuery plugins: 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Plugin-To-Convert-English-Numbers-To-Persian-persianumber.html

**Solution**:
File: `app/design/frontend/[your-package]/[your-theme]/template/page/footer.phtml`
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getJsUrl('persianumber.min.js') ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
    jQuery(function(){
       jQuery('.price').persiaNumber('ar');
    });
</script>
```

**Notes**:
- Upload the jQuery plugin file: persianumber.min.js to `js/` folder
- If you haven't loaded the jQuery file then load it.

Comment: thank you. but can you tell me how to apply it in magento? i mean where to exactly copy that. im new in magento. can you give details? 
@MagePsycho

Comment: @Moh3n I have edited my Answer. Please check.

Comment: how can i apply it for other pages like onepagecheckout or else?